# react native : There is way pass the "list" parameter to screen1 and screen2 without navigate to screen2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

There is way pass the "list" parameter to screen1 and screen2 without navigate to screen2

In my example i move parameter data "list" to screen1 while navigate to screen1 , i want also use this parameter in screen2 , what is the way to do it ?
**I need use with hooks and navigation 5 .**

```
onPress={() => {
              const fromDate = params.fromDate;
              const toDate = params.toDate;
              if (
                Array.isArray(listSelectedWaterSourceCode) === true &&
                listSelectedWaterSourceCode.length > 0
              ) {
                ListOfTheFlat(listSelectedWaterSourceCode, fromDate, toDate)
                  .then((list) => {
                    navigation.navigate('screen1', {
                      list,
                    });
                  })
                  .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
              }
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can achieve that by using [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Another solution is [redux](https://redux.js.org/). You can read their official documentation for that.